# cpanel hosting emails not working with AWS DNS servers name

Tags: amazon-web-services, cpanel, web-hosting, shared-hosting

**info**: i have two hosting server one is on **skyhost.com** and the other is on AWS **Lightsail**. **skyhost** is a cpanel hosting where i register my domain name and my emails accounts. My website is hosted on **AWS Lightsail**  with the domain. my website is contain the domain which is register on **skyhost**. The website is working fine because **AWS** DNS are propagated with domain which is register on skyhost.

**Issue**: But the email `info@mycompany.com` are not working (sending or receiving). I am not able to login the accounts since i host my website on **AWS** because i don't understand how can i add DNS records in **Lightsail AWS** of skyhost  for mail exchange or something else...

**example**: (65.91.30.99) that is the ip of cpnel skyhost. **staticip-1** that is a AWS server ip

[image]

Comment: When you say "emails are not working", are you referring to emails from an email account on cPanel? Or emails from the website? Or emails from email accounts with AWS?

Comment: this is the email `info@mycompany.com`. my domain name is `mycompany.com`

Comment: I'm sorry, but that doesn't answer my question. Try removing the "mail." from your MX record. Typically, you would have an A record for mail.example.com that points at 65.91.20.99, then an MX record for example.com that points at mail.example.com. So, your current setup looks like you got something mixed up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To keep it simple, the MX records do not point to IPs.

You will need to set the sub-domain to the naked domain example.com or "@" in some cases. (I have not used the light sail DNS console before)

But you then set up the "Maps to" as mail.example.com and then create an A record for mail.example.com to point to 65.91.30.99

This is how basic DNS routing works for email.

More info here: https://lightsail.aws.amazon.com/ls/docs/en_us/articles/lightsail-how-to-create-dns-entry